# Adding Table Header to JSON Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to Javascript/jQuery and I need some help adding a header to my table.  I am getting my data from a JSON array.  Here is the code I currently have.

```
function jsonTable (ChartNum, divclass) {
"use strict";
var output = JSON.parse(document.getElementById(ChartNum).innerHTML);
var table = $('<table></table>');
for (var i=0; i < output.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
for (var key in output[i]) {
    var td = $('<td></td>');
    td.attr('class', key);
    td.text(output[i][key]);
    tr.append(td);
}
table.append(tr);
}
$(divclass).append(table);
}


jsonTable( 'pdfChart1', '#pdfTable1');
```

Any help would be really appreciated.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function jsonTable (ChartNum, divclass) {"use strict";
var output = JSON.parse(document.getElementById(ChartNum).innerHTML);
var table = $('<table></table>');
var trHeader = $('var table = $('<tr><th>Column1</th><th>Column2</th>    <th>ColumnsN</th></tr>');
table.append(trHeader);
for (var i=0; i < output.length; i++) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
for (var key in output[i]) {
var td = $('<td></td>');
td.attr('class', key);
td.text(output[i][key]);
tr.append(td);
}
table.append(tr);
}
$(divclass).append(table);
}

jsonTable( 'pdfChart1', '#pdfTable1');
```

I added variable trHeader where you can add the name of your columns, of course this will only work if your columns are always the same. Or you can get another json with the names of columns and iterate over it to build trHeader in a similar way you build the tds.